# RecylcerView with a lot of items loading too slow

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView that displays the total usage of each app, it's not perfect, but it's good enough. It's located in my Dashboard fragment and I have a bottom NavBar and when I switch to that fragment with the recyclerview it loads for about 2,5s on my device where there are lot of items in the list and loads for about ,5s on another device that is used less. Is there a way to optimize this and minimize the load time?

Fragment Code:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    count = view.findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentText);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    if (!checkForPermission(getActivity())) {
        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000;
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getActivity().getSystemService("usagestats");
    List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);


    for (UsageStats us : queryUsageStats) {
        Drawable icon;

        final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai;

        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( us.getPackageName(), 0);
            icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(us.getPackageName());
        } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            ai = null;
            icon = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "Package name not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");

        if (us.getTotalTimeInForeground() / 60000 > 0) {
            if (applicationName.equals("(unknown)")) {
                other += us.getTotalTimeInForeground();
            } else {
                list.add(new AppListModel(applicationName + " = " +  us.getTotalTimeInForeground() / 60000 + " mins", icon));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, us.getPackageName() + " = " + us.getTotalTimeInForeground());
            totalUsage += us.getTotalTimeInForeground() / 60000;
        }
    }

    int totalUsageHrs = (int) totalUsage / 60;
    int totalUsageMin = (int) totalUsage - totalUsageHrs * 60;

    if (totalUsageHrs == 0) {
        count.setText(totalUsageMin + " minutes");
    } else {
        count.setText(totalUsageHrs + " hours, " + totalUsageMin + " minutes");
    }

    list.add(new AppListModel("Other = " + other, null));

    adapter = new RVAdapter(getActivity(), list);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    return view;
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<AppListModel> list;

@NonNull
@Override
public RVAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

public RVAdapter(Context context, List<AppListModel> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RVAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mainText.setText(list.get(position).getAppName());
    holder.appImage.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).getAppImage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mainText;
    private ImageView appImage;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mainText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemTxt);
        appImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemImage);
    }
}}
```